# Compiling JAVA class file within TomCat Server

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a class file that creates a monthly report by talking with a MySQL database, it also creates graphs as JPEGs (Hence why it must be in the TomCat Directory and not compiled as an app)

The front end simply uses this data to display a "Monthly Report".

My problem is I cannot figure out how to run the class file once it's compiled from the server. The Class file works 100% in eclipse and then automatically publishes to a server (locally).

I'm trying to compile the JAVA class file and run it locally on a Windows machine, the live version is on a Linux environment.

Here's what I have so far:

So compiling the class and running it: (Tried with -cp as well)

```
java C:\p_sys\tomcat\webapps\PR\WEB-INF\classes\au\gov\vic\pdd\PPA createreportsmonthly
```

We get the following error:

```
C:\p_sys\tomcat\webapps\PR\WEB-INF\classes\au\gov\vic\pdd\PPA\createreportsmonthly>java CreateMonthlyReportTable
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: CreateMonthlyReportTa
ble (wrong name: au/gov/vic/ppd/PPA/createreportsmonthly/CreateMonthlyReportT
able)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Can anyone help me out here?

*** EDIT

Some clarity

CreateMonthlyReportTable.class is located within: 
C:\p_sys\tomcat\webapps\PR\WEB-INF\classes\au\gov\vic\pdd\PPA\

Comment: what is `au.gov.vic.pdd.PPA`? what is `createreportsmonthly`? what is `CreateMonthlyReportTable`? where are they how do they interact.

Comment: Just to clarify , do you want your class file to run on windows locally OR on unix environment where tomcat already loaded your file in its one of the webapp ?

Comment: On the unix environment but I'd like to test on the Windows one too if that's ok.

Comment: You must be specifying package for your `CreateMonthlyReportTable` Java file. Try accessing it with the fully qualified name

Answer (score -1):

have you tried

`java -cp C:/p_sys/tomcat/webapps/PR/WEB-INF/classes<space> au.gov.vic.pdd.PPA.CreateMonthlyReportTable`

should be a space character

Comment: @Olly Dixon: does CreateMonthlyReportTable contain the main method. what is it's package name?